# Managed Package - permissions for dynamically generated Visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, metadata-api, permissions

We're working on a yet-unreleased managed package using Salesforce DX. It seems to be standard in DX to manage most permissions in a more portable way via permission sets rather than profiles so we've been putting our components into two role-based permission sets (one for Admin, one for User).

One functionality we're building in our admin setup UI is a one-click ability (via Metadata API) to generate Visualforce wrapper pages for our VF component, so that they can add our component to record pages for their own custom objects. What occurred to me though is, these pages will be generated in the subscriber's namespace with only admin visibility.

It's my understanding that our packaged code would not be able to use Apex to add a component from the subscriber's namespace to our packaged Permission Sets (am I right?). Any thoughts on the best flow for handling permissions of dynamically-generated components in an admin setup UI?